# how to call "Class" class as parameter in java

Tags: java

for example I have following  method in class BugReportFactory:

```
public static void addFactoryImpl(Class impl) { }
```

I want to call this method from another class by following ways:

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(new BugReportFactoryAndroid());
```

It says that following Argument is not applicable for Class class.

Can anyone tell my mistake?

ONE MORE QUESTION:

```
private static IBugReportFactory INSTANCE = null; 
public static void addFactoryImpl(Class impl) { 
INSTANCE = (IBugReportFactory)impl; 
}
```

But it shows errors specifying that you cannot cast class to object?

Comment: Guys..you all are correct..Its working. ONE MORE QUESTION:                      private static IBugReportFactory INSTANCE = null;               public static void addFactoryImpl(Class impl) {                INSTANCE = (IBugReportFactory)impl; } But it shows errors specifying that you cannot cast

Comment: I cannot change the "IBugReportFactory" to "Class" because my another methods are using this instance and i need instance of this class in that method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following, `Object` class has a [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(new BugReportFactoryAndroid().getClass());
```

Or

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactoryAndroid.class);
```

Will do the job.

> ONE MORE QUESTION:
>
> ```
> private static IBugReportFactory INSTANCE = null; 
> public static void addFactoryImpl(Class impl) { 
>      INSTANCE = (IBugReportFactory)impl; 
> }
> ```
>
> But it shows errors specifying that you cannot cast

Class is different instance is different. Change your `INSTANCE` Variable type as `Class`.

```
private static Class INSTANCE = null;
public static void addFactoryImpl(Class impl) { 
     INSTANCE = impl; 
}
```

Class is blue print of an instance. You can't assign an instance to Class reference. Both are two different things.

Comment: Or simply BugReportFactoryAndroid.class

Comment: @EyalSchneider : Was on the way of adding it.

Comment: I cannot change the "IBugReportFactory" to "Class" because my another methods are using this instance and i need instance of this class in that method

Answer (score 4):

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactoryAndroid.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Class is some kind of blueprint for an object. 
When you call `new X()`, you create a new object of the `class X`, which means, you build a new class following the **blueprint of X**.

In your case, the blueprint is wanted, so you need to put `BugReportFactoryAndroid.class`

Read more at http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-object-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactoryAndroid.class);
```

Or:

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl((new BugReportFactoryAndroid()).getClass());
```

I personally prefer the first one.

Answer (score 1):

(ObjectInstance).getClass() or (Class Name).class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the class in your method, the calling code will be:

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactoryAndroid.class);
```

If you actually wanted to pass an instance of this class, then your method signature should change to:

```
public static void addFactoryImpl(Object impl) { }
```

OR

```
public static <T> void addFactoryImpl(T impl) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't think you want to pass a class of type [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) as argument. This is a special class used for reflection purposes.

In the case of the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) design pattern, typically you have a common interface describing the factory API, and multiple implementations of this interface:

```
public interface BugReportFactory {
  public A createA();
  public B createB();
}

public class BugReportFactoryAndroid implements BugReportFactory {..}

public class BugReportFactoryIOS implements BugReportFactory {..}
```

And the class that invokes the factory methods may look like:

```
public class Foo {
  private List<BugReportFactory> factories = new ArrayList<BugReportFactory>(); 

  public void addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactory factory) { 
    factories.add(factory);
  }

  public void createAll() {
    for (BugReportFactory f : factories) {
      A a = f.createA(); 
      B b = f.createB();
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution both of my Problem: It is as follow:

```
private static IBugReportFactory INSTANCE = null;
public static void addFactoryImpl(Class<?> impl) {
    Object factoryImpl = null;
    try {
        factoryImpl = impl.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    INSTANCE = (IBugReportFactory) factoryImpl;
}
```

If you want to call this method, it is like this way:

```
BugReportFactory.addFactoryImpl(BugReportFactoryAndroid.class);
```

Thanks Everyone for your support and help.